# How can I convert a string to JSON in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this string `{id: evt_1jopsdgqxhp78yqp7pujesee, created: 2021-08-14t16:38:17z}` and would like to convert it to a JSON, I tried parse_json but got an error, to_variant and converted to "{id: evt_1jopsdgqxhp78yqp7pujesee, created: 2021-08-14t16:38:17z}"

Comment: What was the error?  Where does the data come from, and can that source add the required `"` around the data values?  Is the data always in that format?  `{id: <text>, created: <text>}` or can it vary with different element names, different number of elements, maybe an array of objects, etc, etc?

Comment: the error was Invalid argument types for function 'TO_JSON': (VARCHAR(16777216)
the data comes from django (backend). the data is always in that format

Comment: To be a `VARCHAR(16777216)` I'm betting that the data is a single string containing many of these items in an array?  In which case, fix the django backend to output properly formed json *(with `"` in the appropriate places)*, or implement an intermediate layer that reads this malformed data and outputs properly formed json *(with `"` in the appropriate places)*, then passes it to your database.  Don't use snowflake to reprocess strings that are millions of characters long.

Comment: That is not valid json. In json, all strings need to be contained with double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

To Gokhan & Simon's point, the original data isn't valid JSON.

If you're 100% (1000%) certain it'll "ALWAYS" come that way, you can treat it as a string parsing exercise and do something like this, but once someone changes the format a bit it'll have an issue.

```
create temporary table abc (str varchar);
insert into abc values ('{id: evt_1jopsdgqxhp78yqp7pujesee, created: 2021-08-14t16:38:17z}');


select to_json(parse_json(json_str)) json_json
FROM (
select split_part(ltrim(str, '{'), ',', 1) as part_a,
   split_part(rtrim(str, '}'), ',', 2) as part_b,
   split_part(trim(part_a), ': ', 1) part_a_name,
   split_part(trim(part_a), ': ', 2) part_a_val,
   split_part(trim(part_b), ': ', 1) part_b_name,
   split_part(trim(part_b), ': ', 2) part_b_val,
   '{"'||part_a_name||'":"'||part_a_val||'", "'||part_b_name||'":"'||part_b_val||'"}' as json_str
FROM abc);
```

which returns a valid JSON

```
{"created":"2021-08-14t16:38:17z","id":"evt_1jopsdgqxhp78yqp7pujesee"}
```

Overall this is very fragile, but if you must do it, feel free to.

Comment: With the OP comment that the error massage was `Invalid argument types for function 'TO_JSON': (VARCHAR(16777216)`, it's more likely that the string is much more than a single 'object'.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid, as you can validate it using any online tool:

https://jsonlint.com/

This is a valid JSON version of your data:

```
{
    "id": "evt_1jopsdgqxhp78yqp7pujesee",
    "created": "2021-08-14t16:38:17z"
}
```

And you can parse it successfully using parse_json:

```
select parse_json('{ "id": "evt_1jopsdgqxhp78yqp7pujesee", "created": "2021-08-14t16:38:17z"}');
```

Comment: Why have you added spaces to the date-time?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: I just copied your sample - spaces should be related to stackoverflow, fixing it

Comment: ***My*** sample?  ;)